# Radio buttons in matrix field not saving

Tags: matrix, craft3, saveentry, onsaveentry

Craft CMS version 3.0.9 (updated from 3.0.1 to try and fix).

I have a layout field in a matrix box with the radio buttons field type with the options `normal (default), full, left, right`.

When saving the entry with the radio button as full, left or right it stays at the default `normal`.

This functionality was working in Craft CMS 2, doesn’t seem to work since the update to 3.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: try disabling all of your plugins and see if the entry is saved correct. 

also make sure you are not using two different names by accident

Answer (score 2):

Steps to fix:

1. Change the radio button default to an alternative option.
2. Go to entry and remove the matrix block.
3. Save entry
4. Readd the matrix block.

You should be able to correctly save the block, a long process but I couldn’t figure out what was going on.